# Idiomatic Haskell for transforming a vector into a 2D matrix?

Tags: haskell

I have a vector of Integers that I'd like to convert into an two-dimensional matrix. The input is guaranteed to be divisible by the row size. What's the most idiomatic way to do this in Haskell?

In Python I would do this:

```
# Taken from itertools docs.
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

m = list(grouper(v, n))
```

Comment: Do you mean a `Vector` from `Data.Vector`? Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: [`chunksOf :: Int -> [e] -> [[e]]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean turning a "vector" represented as a Haskell list into a "matrix" represented as a list of lists, then an idiomatic solution is likely to use `splitAt` to break off each row, building the list of rows **EITHER** using straightforward pattern matching and recursion:

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf _ [] = []
chunksOf n xs =
  let (row, rest) = splitAt n xs
  in  row : chunksOf n rest
```

possibly with a guard to avoid embarrassing endless loops:

```
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n | n > 0 = chunks
  where
    chunks [] = []
    chunks xs =
      let (row, rest) = splitAt n xs
      in  row : chunks rest
```

**OR ELSE** using `unfoldr`:

```
import Data.List
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n | n > 0 = unfoldr chunk
  where
    chunk [] = Nothing
    chunk xs = Just (splitAt n xs)
```

If the length is not a multiple of the row length, the final row will be shorter than the rest.  To allow a fill character for the final incomplete row, you might write:

```
import Data.List
chunksOfWithFill :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOfWithFill n filler | n > 0 = unfoldr chunk
  where
    chunk xs = case splitAt n xs of
      ([],[]) -> Nothing
      (xs,[]) -> Just (fill xs, [])
      result  -> Just result
    fill xs = take n (xs ++ repeat filler)
```

As @Will Ness notes in the comments, `chunksOf` is already available in the `Data.List.Split` module of the `split` package.